# Local file send jQuery AJAX GET, success, but data undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I wrote a simple code in local html file to test jQuery AJAX, as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://hqdigi2.eastmoney.com/EM_Quote2010NumericApplication/CompatiblePage.aspx?Type=Z2&r=1386912455181&fav=300251",
      dataType: "script",
      dataFilter: function(data, type) {
        console.log("### type: " + type+", data: " + data);
      },
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("****success: " + data + ", status: " + status);
        console.log("xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
      },
      error: function(jqXhr, status, err) {
        console.log("!!!!Error - xhr:" + jqXhr + ", status: " + status + ", " + err);
      }
    });
});
```

After executed, the console shows:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://hqdigi2.eastmoney.com/EM_Quote2010NumericApplication/CompatiblePage.aspx?Type=Z2&r=1386912455181&fav=300251&_=1387173844186". 
### type: script text, data: undefined 
****success: undefined, status: success 
xhr.responseText: undefined
```

But the response realy returned as below:

```
var stockData={DataList:["2,300251,aStockName,41.64,1.19%,0.49,41.57,0,41.64,0,160955,66550,41.30,41.15,42.15,40.38,1,198,0"],UpDatetime:"2013-12-16 14:48:27"};
```

How can I get this response text?

I also tried to change the dataType to "text", but Chrome complains the Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I don't want to disable the security setting of Chrome to allow local file cross-domain access.

Sorry for tht bad format, because my network issue, some css/js file missed on cdn.sstatic.net

Answer (score 0):

I tried it again and again, and finally I found I can get the response object stockData from success callback! And the dataType set to "script" (or use the $.getScript).
One more thing I am not understand is the dataType - only script and jsonp could get the response, text,json or html will be prevented by remote domain access error.